# Conditional time plot using R?

Tags: r, plot

I have calculated some statistical values of an Enviromental Index over a number of zones using Grass and I saved them as a csv file with the purpose of using R to create a time plot based on those values.

I succefully created my dataset with which has this format :

```
> head(Dataset) 
  year month zone       min       max      mean     stddev coeff_var
1 2000     5    1 0.2735742 0.4776645 0.4300383 0.02908890  6.764259
2 2000     5    2 0.2325166 0.4304893 0.3759373 0.02497549  6.643526
3 2000     5    3 0.2747173 0.4729956 0.4295689 0.02320233  5.401307
4 2000     5    4 0.2891487 0.4878779 0.4350567 0.02775799  6.380316
5 2000     5    5 0.2757515 0.4625435 0.4201794 0.02054300  4.889103
6 2000     5    6 0.2338618 0.4670695 0.4003526 0.02451026  6.122170
.    .     .    .         .         .         .          .         .
3025 2010     9   55 0.2901262 0.5364349 0.4868686 0.03559649  7.311314
```

How do I create a Time plot in R which will show how the "mean" value differates over the time (year,month) for a specific zone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is defined as follows:

```
Dataset <- data.frame(year=numeric(6), month = numeric(6), 
                      mean = numeric(6), zone = numeric(6))
Dataset$month <- c(10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3)
Dataset$mean <- c(.43, .37, .43, .44, .42, .40)
Dataset$zone <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

You can define a new column with a date object using the `paste` function and converting to a date with `as.Date`.

```
Dataset$date <- as.Date(paste(Dataset$year, 
                              Dataset$month, 
                              rep("01", nrow(Dataset)), sep="-"), 
                        format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

And then plot using the `plot` function

```
plot(Dataset$mean, Dataset$date)
```

If you want to show only one zone, you can subset your dataset when plotting

```
plot(Dataset$mean[Dataset$zone == 1], Dataset$date[Dataset$zone == 1])
```

Comment: It works! WoW that trick creating a new field, was the key! And I was fighting with conditionals for the better part of this day! Suddenly i feel the need to learn more for R :)